# Can I "inherit" another enum in an untagged serde enum?

Tags: rust, serde

In my project, I had a single `enum Downloadable` type containing many sources and I decided to **split** most of the sources that dont need to be in Downloadable (1) into `enum ServerType`. However I still want to support the Downloadable variants inside ServerType for both compatibility and because its kind of a feature.

1: i have a `struct Server` that contains `plugins/mods: Vec<Downloadable>` and `jar: Downloadable` (which acts like the server itself) - whenever i want to add a new server type, i have to do more work because Downloadable contains methods about plugin/mod metadata and more. That's why I wanted to split it (keep `plugins/mods: Vec<Downloadable>` but change `jar: ServerType`)

```rs
#[serde(tag = "type", rename_all = "lowercase")]
pub enum ServerType {
    Vanilla {},

    // -- snip --

    Downloadable {
        #[serde(flatten)]
        inner: Downloadable,
    },
}

#[serde(tag = "type", rename_all = "lowercase")]
pub enum Downloadable {
    // most variants and fields omitted for readability
    GithubReleases { ... },
    URL { ... },
    Jenkins { ... },
}
```

But this kinda didnt work out.

| Config | Error |
| --- | --- |
| `type = "jenkins"` | unknown variant `jenkins`, expected one of <...> (src: ServerType deser) |
| `type = "downloadable"` | missing field `type` (src: Downloadable deser) |

...and having 2 `type` values is impossible

What can I do?

<sup>ps. first question on s/o constructive criticism appreciated</sup>

## Solution:

1. add a new [enum](https://github.com/ParadigmMC/mcman/blob/48b0098567a12d8275560285a6dd9352a1b6e927/src/model/servertype/mod.rs#L29-L34):

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum Bridge {
    ServerType(ServerType),
    Downloadable(Downloadable),
}
```

2. [`impl From<Bridge> for ServerType`](https://github.com/ParadigmMC/mcman/blob/48b0098567a12d8275560285a6dd9352a1b6e927/src/model/servertype/mod.rs#L100-L107)
3. added custom [deserialize/serialize functions](https://github.com/ParadigmMC/mcman/blob/48b0098567a12d8275560285a6dd9352a1b6e927/src/model/servertype/mod.rs#L109-L121) that use Bridge to deser
4. added this to [Server](https://github.com/ParadigmMC/mcman/blob/48b0098567a12d8275560285a6dd9352a1b6e927/src/model/server.rs#L37):

```
struct Server {
    #[serde(with = "super::servertype")]
    pub jar: ServerType
}
```

and it works :3 thanks

Comment: Best I could figure out is [have `ServerType` be a common ancestor for `Downloadable` and a new `ServerTypeOnly`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1275cc8e9e040a3440c3b161ba2cd14)